# Stop New Relic / Celery From Polluting Logs on Heroku

Tags: python, django, celery, newrelic

## Question

How can you stop New Relic / Celery from constantly printing the below to Heroku's log.

```
app[scheduler.1]: [INFO/MainProcess] Starting new HTTP connection (1): collector-6.newrelic.com
app[scheduler.1]: [INFO/MainProcess] Starting new HTTP connection (1): collector-6.newrelic.com
app[scheduler.1]: [INFO/MainProcess] Starting new HTTP connection (1): collector-6.newrelic.com
app[scheduler.1]: [INFO/MainProcess] Starting new HTTP connection (1): collector-6.newrelic.com
```

### Setup

The above log entries appear every minute. The app reporting this is a celery worker started via `Procfile` that reads (in part):

```
scheduler: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=ERROR -B -E --maxtasksperchild=1000
```

Despite setting `loglevel` to `ERROR` it appears that celery is ignoring this argument. Interestingly enough, on my local machine, this setting is respected.

#### Versions

```
celery==3.0.12
django-celery==3.0.11
newrelic==1.6.0.13
```

Comment: The log message is actually coming from the 'requests' module embedded within the 'newrelic' package. You need to somehow have the logging module or Celery suppress any logging from 'newrelic.lib.requests'. I don't know how you can do that for your setup so not providing this as the answer.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the insight Graham. Let me see if I can figure it out and I'll post my solution if I find one.

Comment: More info: It comes from `urllib3`, packaged in `requests` packaged in `newrelic`. [See entry](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/develop/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L190) in `requests`. Investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution, per New Relic support, is to add the below to your settings.py or a celeryconfig.py (depending on which you use for celery settings).

```
import logging
class RequestsConnectionFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return False
logging.getLogger('newrelic.lib.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool').addFilter(RequestsConnectionFilter())
```

NR support told me they plan to build this suppression into future versions of the python agent.